# query to combine the result of two columns into one with alternate values in MYSQL

Tags: mysql

I need a query to combine the two different columns of the same table in a single column with alternate values.

Table: **tblDemo**

```
Id | Name
_________
1  |  A
2  |  B
3  |  C
```

Required **output**:

```
Result
______
  1
  A
  2
  B
  3
  C
```

Comment: This is a very strange request.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming `name` is not null, you can use

```
select coalesce(name, id) as Result from
(
  select id, name from tblDemo
  union all
  select id, null from tblDemo
) as subquery
order by id, name;
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use UNION

```
select id as result from tbldemo union select name as result from tbldemo
```

Comment: union combines the result set of two or more columns one after another, I need it to be displayed as I have specified in the question.

Answer (score 0):

If Id is varchar/nvarchar then:

```
select Result from (
select Id as 'Result' from tblDemo
union all
select Name as 'Result'from tblDemo) A
```

And if Id is int then you should use this:

```
select Result from (
select CAST(Id as nvarchar(max)) as 'Result' from tblDemo
union all
select Name as 'Result'from tblDemo) A
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT id value,id my_order FROM my_table
 UNION
SELECT name,id FROM my_table
 ORDER 
    BY my_order,value;
```